# Portcmis Alfresco improving GetChildren() performance

Tags: c#, alfresco, cmis

i'm trying to use GetChildren() on a folder chose by users and returning it to Json,
but i got very poor performance like several minutes to display items, so i made a lot of search and with

```
public string GetAllJson(IFolder obj, PortCMIS.Client.ISession session)
    {
        try
        {
            //IOperationContext oc = session.CreateOperationContext();
            //oc.FilterString = "cmis:objectId,cmis:name,cmis:createdBy";

            IOperationContext oc = OperationContextUtils.CreateMinimumOperationContext("cmis:objectId", "cmis:name");

            List<ICmisObject> lst = new List<ICmisObject>();
            foreach (var item in obj.GetChildren(oc))
            {
                if (item is IFolder || item is IDocument)
                {
                    lst.Add(item);
                }           
            }
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lst);
            return json;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Message = "Erreur dans la récupération des enfants(dossier(s) et/ou document(s)) : " + e.Message;
            return null;
        }
    }
```

it work well and performance are more satisfying but not enough,  the Json is still like 25,000 lines for 10 children,
and the root folder 114,000 for 12 children

i wonder if someone succeed in getting only the metadata i need (name,id), maybe by query or override

thanks

Comment: When you added `Stopwatch`es, where was the time being spent? In the `GetChildren` call? In `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`? Somewhere else?

Comment: yes the GetChildren Call

Comment: Can you replicate the same on an out-of-the-box Alfresco? If not, it might be because of your Alfresco customization? (for instance adding tons of properties)